# Custom Ribbon Button SelectionCount rule not always working

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a set of ribbon buttons on my CRM entity that use an enable rule so that they are available only when a single record in the view is selected, any more or less and the buttons should no longer be enabled.

This does work, but it has occasions where it won't what it is meant to. Sometimes I click into the view and select a field and the buttons remain disabled, or I click on several and they are still enabled.

Is this just a flaw in how they work or do I need to add something extra to ensure that they work every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable rule for specific ribbon button should be like:

```
<EnableRules>
            <EnableRule Id="crm.Form.contact.MainTab.Collaborate.SendNotif.Command.EnableRule.OrRule">
              <OrRule>
                <Or>
                  <FormStateRule State="ReadOnly" />
                </Or>
                <Or>
                  <FormStateRule State="Existing" />
                </Or>
              </OrRule>
            </EnableRule>
            <EnableRule Id="crm.Form.contact.MainTab.Collaborate.SendNotif.Command.EnableRule.RecordPrivilegeRule">
              <RecordPrivilegeRule AppliesTo="PrimaryEntity" PrivilegeType="AppendTo" />
            </EnableRule>
            <EnableRule Id="crm.HomepageGrid.contact.MainTab.Collaborate.SendNotif.Command.EnableRule.SelectionCountRule">
              <SelectionCountRule AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Maximum="1" Minimum="1" />
            </EnableRule>
          </EnableRules>
```

In sample above, main part is:

```
<EnableRule Id="crm.HomepageGrid.contact.MainTab.Collaborate.SendNotif.Command.EnableRule.SelectionCountRule">
      <SelectionCountRule AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Maximum="1" Minimum="1" />
</EnableRule>
```

If you are using [Visual Ribbon Editor for crm 2011](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/) (I recommend) enable rule tab should be like:

[image]

Compare your settings with this example. This works, verified :)

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah that matches what I've got too, in the visual ribbon editor. I wonder, if the system was having brief performance drops when I was selecting or deselecting records could that somehow stop the enable rule from working properly?

Comment: It looks like the problem could be because it is in a subgrid, as I have tried it in the main view (homepage) for an entity and it works fine there

Answer (score 0):

I has been 8 years now, but someone could find this useful :)

Try adding `distinct="true"` to your view fetchxml

```
<fetchxml>
   <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
      <entity name="entity">
         <attribute name="attribute" />
      </entity>
   </fetch>
</fetchxml>
```

If you are using minimum=1 and maximum=1 in your SelectionCountRule then when records overflow to another page you may have some issues of SelectionCountRule being false even tho you selected certain record.